# electronegativity and hydrogen bonding

Tags: intermolecular-forces, hydrogen-bond, electronegativity

I have a basic idea why, but can someone just confirm, why chlorine isn't able to hydrogen bond despite the fact that it has the same electronegativity value as nitrogen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

H-bonding only occurs between a hydrogen bonded covalently to oxygen, fluorine or nitrogen, and another oxygen, fluorine or nitrogen bonded to a hydrogen.It does not matter that chlorine has the same electronegativity as nitrogen because (i assume you mean H-Cl) chlorine is larger than the O,F or N so its electron density is lesser than these elements. If you meant Cl-Cl, there is no difference in electronegativity between the two atoms so polarity = 0.

Comment: That is true of the _strongest_ hydrogen bonds.  But, as other questions/answers under the hydrogen-bonding tag point out, there are also hydrogen bond interactions involving heavier halogens and even carbon.  Shakespeare:  "There are more worlds, Horatio, than are dreamt of in [routine] philosophy."